# A relative topology problem

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be any space, and assume $X=E_1 \cup E_2$, where $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ are closed in $X$. Let $B \subset E_{1}$ be such that $B \cap E_{2} \subset Q$ where $Q$ is open in $E_{2}$. Show that $B\subset \mathrm{Int}\,(E_{1} \cup Q)$.

What should I do to show the containment?

I do not have a clear idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution but maybe there's a simpler one (I am assuming $Int$ is interior).

We are going to consider the partition:
$B=(B\cap E_2)\cup (B\cap E_{2}^c)$.

Notice that $B\cap E_2^c\subseteq E_2^c\subseteq E_1\subseteq (E_1\cup Q)$. Since $E_2^c$ is open, $E_2^c\cap B\subseteq Int(E_1\cup Q)$.

For the other part of the partition, notice that
since $Q\cap E_2$ is open in $E_2$, we must have that $Q^c\cap E_2$ is closed in $E_2$ and since $E_2$ is closed in $X$, $Q^c\cap E_2$ is closed in $X$.

Since $E_2\cap B\subseteq Q\subseteq Q\cup E_2^c\subseteq Q\cup E_1$

Finally, $E_2^c\cup Q$ is open, so it has to be contained in $Int(E_1\cup Q)$.

Comment: I think you put $(Q\cap E_2^c)^c=Q\cup E_2^c$.

Comment: youre right, sorry

Comment: I corrected it and now it seems ok